# State of the art of the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

What is the most general form of the Implicit Function Theorem? Quite a general form of this theorem was given by Kumagai (1980): An implicit function theorem. So I am  wondering what are the weakest assumption we have to make in order to obtain an implicit function theorem...